# How to upload Composer output to shared host?

Tags: php, git, quickbooks-online

My first time using Composer, mostly because vendor-supplied SDK docs only cover a Composer-based install. I am attempting to get set up to use the QuickBooks Online (QBO) SDK found here: https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK

I have done this:

```
Steves-Mac-Mini:~ steve$ composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk
Using version ^3.4 for quickbooks/v3-php-sdk
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing quickbooks/v3-php-sdk (V3.4.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Steves-Mac-Mini:~ steve$
```

This left me with:

```
- composer.lock
- composer.json
- vendor
    - autoload.php
    - composer
        - autoload_*.php files
        - installed.json
    - quickbooks
        - v3-php-sdk
            - more composer.json, composer.lock, and other various files
            - src
                - Directories for each "Class" name
            - test
```

I'm a little confused on what to actually upload to the site at a minimum to make this work. I want to eliminate all the "examples", documentation, and folders that shouldn't be "public" (I read a lot about not uploading the "vendor" directory, but that seemed to apply to git users).

I am **not** using Git or any version control system on the site. Just FTP. I think this is where my confusion comes from after reading similar questions on SO and the web.

What all do I need to upload, and what files should not be renamed or moved?

Comment: You're only need the `vendor/quickbooks/src/*`, you can use `composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk --prefer-dist --no-dev` to have a minimal install.

Comment: Saying that though, there is 1 file in tests which is 9 lines, so it's not much or a cleanup. You can remove `_Samples/` folder also, if you look at the psr-4 namespace its `QuickBooksOnline\API` so basically any file which has that at the top you cant remove.

Comment: --no-dev is not a valid switch. I will try uploading vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/*. I hate that I'm not able to rename any of those directories without breaking everything though...

Comment: Why do you need to rename them? It's fundamental on how psr-4 autoloading works.. You could fork the lib and then change in the composer.json the autoload namespace then find and replace all the namespaces in all the files, commit, add to packagist and then pull down your own, but why? the vendor dir should not affect your code (dont place your files in there)

Comment: Also no web access to the vendor folder should ever be needed so you should prevent that either by placing it outside your webroot or preventing access to it with a .htaccess or in the server config.